# Implement single signon (SSO) using SAML in java and AzureAD as IDP

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml

I want to implement Single signOn on my web application using SAML where Azure Ad will be the Identity Provider. I need to know what is `entityId`, `appId` and and how to create `metadata.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details you seek are available in this site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-federation-metadata
All the details present in FederationMetadata.xml file depends on what is configured on Azure AD. 
As a Web application developer, you don't need to create this XML file. It should be provided by the person who is managing Azure AD. If you are the person managing Azure AD also, then you can download it from there.

Comment: Hi Naveen, I am new to single signon. i want to know how should i implement it in java spring application. i have read the docs but a bit confuse. i also want to know what details should i ask from my identity provider?

Comment: It is a huge concept and cannot be explained completely here. You need to read about it on Internet. There are plenty of examples (even with code) available. All you need from IdP (Identity Provider) is FederationMetadata.xml. You need to deploy it in your application. Prepare authentication request to IdP from your app and send the request. IdP will return you SAMLResponse in XML format. If the provided credentials are valid, response will be valid. You need to check the status of the response and allow the user to enter your application. This is very basic explanation of SAML authentication.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0 contains useful information before starting implementation. Please accept answer if you find my inputs helpful.

Comment: If you have a Spring-based web-based, then use the Spring Security SAML extension. It's one of the most complete SAML SP implementations for Java.